# Accessing a JavaRDD in Pyspark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

In Apache Zeppelin, I have created a JavaRDD object by calling a static function of a class loaded from a Java JAR. Is it possible to access this JavaRDD using Pyspark?

I have been able to work around this issue by the following inefficient 
approach. I would be glad to see a cleaner solution.

> Java part:
>
> 1. Map the contents of the RDD to their serialized versions (e.g. JSON strings).
> 2. Write the mapped RDD to a Spark SQL table.
>
> Python part:
>
> 1. Access the table from the SqlContext.
> 2. Get the RDD of table and map its contents back to their deserialized version.

Comment: Can you add your workaround as an answer?  I'd love to see it. (This would also allow you to remove the workaround from the question)

Answer (score 2):

I found a method that should work in most of the cases. It has two stages:

First, get a handle to the Java object in a Python environment: as described in [this](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/interpreter/spark.html) doc page, the ZeppelinContext class contains put() and get() methods for sharing data between different environments.

```
%spark    
z.put("rdd", rddToConvert) // z is the ZeppelinContext object.

%pyspark    
rddFromJava = z.get("rdd")
```

Second, convert the Java RDD to a Python RDD. I took the code from [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5361).

```
from pyspark.rdd import RDD    
pythonRdd = RDD(sc._jvm.SerDe.javaToPython(rddFromJava, sc)
```

Comment: In my case I'm trying to convert a pairRDD from java. Using this method, my resulting `pythonRdd` contains scala.Tuple2s... do you know how to convert these to python objects?

Answer (score 1):

PySpark provides functions for converting RDD (java <-> python):

```
from pyspark.mllib.common import _py2java, _java2py

pythonRDD = _java2py(sc, rddFromJava)

javaRDD = _py2java(sc, rddFromPython)
```